# TENGO UN PROBLEMA DE POINTER NULL y me cuando llamo a una función configurarMaquina

Tags: java

```
[estoy haciendo la simulación de una maquina de dulces][1]
```

[image: donde esta el circulo rojo es donde me da el error]

[image: y el error es cuando llamo a esa función]

si me pueden ayudar les quedaría muy agradecido

```
package com.clearminds.maquina;

import com.clearminds.componentes.Celda;
import com.clearminds.componentes.Producto;

public class MaquinaDulces {
    private Celda celda1;
    private Celda celda2;
    private Celda celda3;
    private Celda celda4;
    private double saldo;
    public Celda getCelda1() {
        return celda1;
    }
    public void setCelda1(Celda celda1) {
        this.celda1 = celda1;
    }
    public Celda getCelda2() {
        return celda2;
    }
    public void setCelda2(Celda celda2) {
        this.celda2 = celda2;
    }
    public Celda getCelda3() {
        return celda3;
    }
    public void setCelda3(Celda celda3) {
        this.celda3 = celda3;
    }
    public Celda getCelda4() {
        return celda4;
    }
    public void setCelda4(Celda celda4) {
        this.celda4 = celda4;
    }
    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }
    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }
    
    public void configurarMaquina(String a, String b, String c, String d){

        celda1.setCodigo(a);
        celda2.setCodigo(b);
        celda3.setCodigo(c);
        celda4.setCodigo(d);
    }
    
    public void mostrarConfiguracion(){
        
        System.out.println(celda1.getCodigo());
        System.out.println(celda2.getCodigo());
        System.out.println(celda3.getCodigo());
        System.out.println(celda4.getCodigo());
        System.out.println(saldo);
    }
}
```

el error me da cuando llamo el metdo onfiguararMaquina este lo estoy llamando desde otra clase tets y me dice que es un error Null Pointer y me dirige a ese método, lo que quiero hacer es asignarle ese string a mis variables Celdas y celda es otra clase creada que tiene 3 atributos pero en este caso solo quiero llenar el atributo código a cada una de mis celdas creadas en esta clase.

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega el còdigo como texto por favor!

Comment: agregue código y una explicación mas profunda

Comment: Y simplemente, en donde de todo ese codigo estas creando las clases celda? no donde las definis, si no donde haces el new?

Comment: el principio creo mis atributos tipo celda con private Celda celda1 y no se si estoy asignandole bien el codigo celda a mis celdas creadas

Comment: @JoseArias Esta bien eso que haces, pero te falta crear el objeto celda1, como dijo @gbianchi, nunca definis `Celda celda1 = new Celda();` ahí mismo o en el constructor de la clase, solo tenes una variable nula y tratas de utilizarla, por lo que causa NullPointerException

Comment: a muchas gracias ya me sirvió @JFrame224, muy crack

Comment: a muchas gracias ya me sirvió @gbianchi, muy crack